# React: Function in .then() doesn't wait for previous .then() functions

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks

In React, I'm making an async API call, updating a React state, and then running a function in a following `.then()` that uses that React state. However, the function runs without the updated state data, even though it's in a `then`. Why is this?

You can see below, how I originally wrote my function. But `sortArray` runs without the updated `foods` state.

```
const [foods, setFoods] = useState([]);

 api
    .getFood('fruits')
    .then((res) => {
      setFoods(res);
     })
    .then(() => sortArray(foods));
```

Instead, I needed to do the below code, that is, write an updater useEffect that waits until the state is set, and then runs the `sortArray` function, which for some reason has the updated `foods` state.

```
const [foods, setFoods] = useState([]);

 api
    .getFood('fruits')
    .then((res) => {
      setFoods(res);
     })
    .then(() => setNeedsSorting(true));

  // cue up sort function
  useEffect(() => {
    if (needsSorting) {
      setNeedsSorting(false);
      sortArray();
    }
  }, [needsSorting, sortArray]);

const sortArray = useCallback(() => {...sorts the foods array...})
```

Why is all this necessary? And how does this successfully grab the updated state, when the original code couldn't?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: 1. You never return anything from that `then` callback, so there is nothing to await. 2. `setFoods` doesn't return a promise, so you can't use `then` anyway. 3. You can't await for state to update. It will be updated in the next render cycle

Comment: @Konrad: then's callback [doesn't even have to return anything](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), yet then will return a promise. Your 2. is misleading.

Comment: Your 3. is correct though.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, you are right, what I meant is that the next `then` won't wait if nothing is returned

Comment: thanks guys, but I also noticed that when I don't put ```setNeedsSorting``` in a ```then``` (just after the api call inside the function), the sorting happens before the state is set... so it seems like the ```then``` is doing something for ```setNeedsSorting```...